# Calendar return wrong time

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I use a calendar for the alarm in my app, but if I use the calendar, the timeInMillis are wrong. 
I show you an example:

```
// Get Current Time
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
calNow.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calNow.add(Calendar.HOUR, calNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calNow.add(Calendar.MINUTE, calNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
long now = calNow.getTimeInMillis();
```

long `now` returns for example: `1345848049917` 
`now` must be the same as `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but it isn't, `system` returns `1345846849921`

`now` is in my timezone: `25.08.2012 - 00:40:49` 
`System.currentTimeMillis()` is: `25.08.2012 - 00:20:49`

Exactly 20 Minutes later, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do, but these rows

```
calNow.add(Calendar.HOUR, calNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calNow.add(Calendar.MINUTE, calNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

doubles the hours and minutes of the day, turning `00:20:49` into `00:40:49`.